# Get employee count under managers recursively in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been searching for about 3 hours for a solution for this, but haven't found something that actually works for me (everything uses `CTE`, but I read that MySQL doesn't support `CTE`).

I have a table of employees that includes hierarchy of `manager <> employee` relationship like so:

```
+----+-----------+-----------+
| id | managerID |   name    |
+----+-----------+-----------+
|  1 |         0 | Joe       |
|  2 |         1 | Melissa   |
|  3 |         1 | Simmons   |
|  4 |         3 | Clarke    |
|  5 |         4 | Lola      |
|  6 |         4 | Britney   |
|  7 |         3 | Suzi      |
|  8 |         4 | Dali Lama |
+----+-----------+-----------+
```

I need a query which takes an `id` of an employee returns the number of employees that are directly and indirectly under him.

e.g: Employee ID `1` will return the count of `7`

e.g: Employee ID `3` will return the count of `5`

How do I go about this?
I just don't get why this is so complicated.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Query to get recursive count of employees under each manager](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19690325/sql-query-to-get-recursive-count-of-employees-under-each-manager)

Comment: I think it's impossible in MySQL if there's no limit on the level of the heirarchy. 

There are several posts talking about it, search for "MySQL heirarchical query"

Comment: You need to use a stored procedure for this logic -- or change your data structure so each row has the complete hierarchy.

Comment: An option, see [WITH RECURSIVE and MySQL](http://guilhembichot.blogspot.com.es/2013/11/with-recursive-and-mysql.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select max(cnt)
  from (
   select @ids:=(
             select group_concat(id)
               from empTab
              where find_in_set(managerID,@ids)>0
          ),
          @cnt:=@cnt+(select count(1)
                        from empTab
                       where find_in_set(id,@ids)>0) as cnt
     from empTab E,
          (select @cnt:=0,@ids:=3) X  -- <--- @ids is starting ID for search 
    limit 6  -- <-- set limit to maximal Tree nesting level or more
  ) X
```

Is slow, but works ...

Comment: OMFG it works like magic!! You have no idea how much I love you right now, you saved my ass!! Thanks a lot!! :)